# Property not displaying when linking between google analytic and webmaster tools

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I already setup all the things in Google analytics.
Also add site as new property in Webmaster search tools.
Add sitemap.xml and robots.txt.

When Click on Google Analytic Account > Admin > Property Setting > Adjust Search Console > Edit it does not display new add property.

What to do for it ?

Search Console display **Monitor the Google Search traffic to Monitor the Google Search traffic to http://www.example.com/**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are the owner of the Website you want to get linked with the Analytics. You will not be able to see the website in the list if you are not the owner of the website.

Hope this helps.